# Fresh Wamp installation: unable to access phpmyadmin & mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, wamp

I am using Windows 8.1, installed the 64-bit Wamp server and unable to access phpmyadmin and mysql. The first error message I got when browsing to phpmyadmin was

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

then I changed my password in config.inc.php and received the following

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

then I changed $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] to http and that did not work either. I tried to access the mysql console, was asked for a password again and nothing happened. So why do they make it so hard? I remember I had no such issue with xampp.

Comment: Do you still have XAMPP installed?

Comment: I do now. Have uninstalled Wamp.